# cocos2d-x 3.12のAndroidでナビゲーションバーを表示する方法

Tags: android, cocos2d-x

以前はAndroidでナビゲーションバーが表示されていたと思うのですが、
cocos2d-x 3.12にしたらデフォルトでナビゲーションバーが表示されないようになりました。
上のステータスバーは表示せず、ナビゲーションバーだけ表示させるようにするにはどうすればいいでしょうか？
Android Studioを使っています。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

v3.12では、AndroidManifest.xmlのテーマの設定は無視されます。
実際に、ステータスバーなどの表示を制御しているのは、下記の部分です。

- プロジェクト/cocos2d/cocos/platform/android/java/src/org/cocos2dx/lib/Cocos2dxActivity.java (419行目～)

```java
protected void hideVirtualButton() {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {

        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION // hide nav bar
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN // hide status bar
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
    }
}
```

この行をコメントアウトすれば、ナビゲーションバーやステータスバーを表示できます。

```
| View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION // hide nav bar
| View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN // hide status bar
```

- ナビゲーションバーだけを表示する場合は、下記のようにします。

```java
protected void hideVirtualButton() {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {

        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
//                          | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION // hide nav bar
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN // hide status bar
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
    }
}
```